# Mantener persistencia de un DIV luego de un Refresh o Reload en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estimadxs, buenos días, quisiera consultarles: ¿Cómo puedo mantener la persistencia de un `div` luego de un **REFRESH/RELOAD**?. Lo que hago es seleccionar un `option` de un `select` para ir mostrando un `div` predeterminado, a través de `jQuery` mantengo la persistencia del `option` luego de que se hizo **REFRESH/RELOAD** en la página. El problema, es que si bien se mantiene seleccionado el `option` el `div` no figura y es ahí donde necesito ayuda, este es el `div`:

```
<div>
  <div class="opc" id="cerDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div class="divTag" style="width: 350px;">
      <p>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
        <span class="spangris">Certificaciones</span>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
      </p>
      <form method="post" onsubmit="return captchaValidar(this)" action="/Home/Pdf">
        <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
        <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Ingrese la solicitud..." required="" title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 5. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 7" onkeypress="return validarCertificadosYSolicitudes(event)" autofocus="">
        <input class="buscar" type="submit" id="btn" value="Buscar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="opc" id="cuoDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div style="width: 350px; ">
      <p>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
        <span class="spangris">Cuotas</span>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="divTag" style="width: 350px;">
      <form id="frmCU" method="post" action="/Cuotas/DetalleCuota">
        <label for="titulo">Título: </label>
        <input type="number" id="titulo" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="titulo" maxlength="6" placeholder="Ingrese su título..." required="" title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 4. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 5" onkeypress="return cuotasYTitulos(event)" autofocus="">
        <input class="buscar" type="submit" id="btn" value="Buscar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="opc" id="solDiv" style="display:none;" data-sort="3">
    <div style="width: 350px;">
      <p>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
        <span class="spangris">Solicitudes</span>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="divTag" style="width: 350px;">
      <form method="post" action="/Solicitudes/Pdf">
        <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
        <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Solicitud..." required="" title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 5. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 7" onkeypress="return validarCertificadosYSolicitudes(event)" autofocus="">
        <input class="buscar" type="submit" id="btn" value="Buscar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="opc" id="titDiv" style="display:none;" data-sort="4">
    <div style="width: 350px;">
      <p>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
        <span class="spangris">Títulos</span>
        <span class="spanrojo">|</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="divTag" style="width: 350px;">
      <form method="post" action="/Titulos/Pdf">
        <label for="titulo">Título: </label>
        <input type="number" id="titulo" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="titulo" maxlength="6" placeholder="Ingrese su título..." required="" title="Sólo  números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 4. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 6" onkeypress="return cuotasYTitulos(event)" autofocus="">
        <input class="buscar" type="submit" id="btn" value="Buscar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el `select` que tengo:

```
<select id="sort-item" class="term">
  <option data-sort="0">ELIJA UNA OPCIÓN</option>
  @foreach (var nivel in Model)
  {
    if (nivel.nivel == 0 || nivel.nivel == 1 || nivel.nivel == 2 || nivel.nivel == 7)
    {
      <option value="cerDiv" data-sort="1">Certificados</option>
      <option value="cuoDiv" data-sort="2">Cuotas</option>
      <option value="solDiv" data-sort="3">Solicitudes</option>
      <option value="titDiv" data-sort="4">Títulos</option>
    }
  }
</select>
```

Y así mantengo la persistencia:

```
let selItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem")) || [];

$(function () {
  if (selItems) {
    selItems.forEach(obj => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
      $("#" + k).val(v)
    })
  }
  $('.term').on("change", function () {
    selItems = $('.term').map(function () {
      return {
        [this.id]: this.value
      }
    }).get();
    console.log(this.value)
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify(selItems))
    mostrarDiv(this.value)
  });
});

function mostrarDiv(target) {
  var opciones = document.getElementsByClassName('opc');
  var tagt = document.getElementById(target);
  var esVisible = tagt.style.display == 'block';

  //ocultar todo
  for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
    opciones[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  //toggle actual
  tagt.style.display = esVisible ? 'none' : 'block';

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Procurá no mezclar código jQuery con JS puro (de hecho hasta parece ser innecesario que uses jQuery). ¿Imprimiste el valor de _tagt_ o el de _target_ en cada llamada a la función _mostrarDiv_?

Comment: Los botones tipo submit ya no deberían utilizarse, se han vuelto mala practica de programación. Murieron con la aparición de AJAX y ahora se han olvidado aun mas con la aparición de las las paginas tipo SPA que llevan a AJAX a su máxima expresión. Si diseñas una página con submit vas en contra de todas estas tecnologias.

Comment: Creo que he encontrado la solución, pero parece incluso innecesario usar jQuery, ya que incluso encontré la solución usando JavaScript puro y visualizando el código. ¿Es jQuery realmente necesario en tu proyecto?

Comment: `sessionStorage` solo mantiene los datos mientras la sesión de navegación está activa, o mejor dicho, es temporal... y puede ser debido a que cuando la sesión se pierda, no te muestre el div persistente... Puedes probar con `localStorage`.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar el código HTML completo para replicar fielmente la página web?

Comment: La página ya venía sin Ajax @abrahamhs

Comment: No es necesario, lo hice así porque estuve siguiendo unos ejemplos. Puede ser js puro @RodrigoRamírez

Comment: Ese es todo el html completo, uso un css solo para diseño pero eso es todo. @cardosource

Comment: El div no figura por que al hacer submit el display vuelve a none, como idea para solucionar eso seria que en javascript crees un flag que indique si se actualizo la pagina y de ahi validar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se mencionó si hay algún mensaje de error que pueda aparecer en la consola del navegador para evaluarlo.

Pero tu código está funcionando correctamente.

Quizás sea el uso de **jQuery** lo que no está configurado de manera correcta.

Antes de usar **jQuery**,:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!------| - mira  - |------>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<!--...........-->


    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   
</body>
```

Así como JavaScript, ahora se necesita hacer el enlace en las páginas donde se debe usar **jQuery**.

```
 $(function(){

        // Código JS / jQuery
        
    })
```

Al colocar todo dentro de este evento, se evitará que una función en un elemento que aún no ha sido cargado genere un error; Todo lo que esté dentro del evento `"Ready"` no se cargará antes de **jQuery**.

Lo que hace tu código es que no muestra el resultado cuando seleccionas la opción "`Titulos`", la última opción. No es un error, sino que nada aparecerá debido a cómo colocaste la función.

> Al reubicar la función dentro del evento Ready, todo funcionará
> correctamente.

```
let selItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem")) || [];

    $(function () {
      if (selItems) {
        selItems.forEach(obj => {
          const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
          $("#" + k).val(v)
        })
      }
      $('.term').on("change", function () {
        selItems = $('.term').map(function () {
          return {
            [this.id]: this.value
          }
        }).get();
        console.log(this.value)
        sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify(selItems))
        mostrarDiv(this.value)
      });
      
      
      //-----------------------
      
      function mostrarDiv(target) {
      var opciones = document.getElementsByClassName('opc');
      var tagt = document.getElementById(target);
      var esVisible = tagt.style.display == 'block';
    
      //ocultar todo
      for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
        opciones[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    
      //toggle actual
      tagt.style.display = esVisible ? 'none' : 'block';
    
      return false;
    }
    });
```

Siguiendo el ejemplo de lo que mencioné y como está funcionando correctamente sin ninguna modificación en el código, simplemente realoqué la función y especificé el enlace de [**jQuery**](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js).

CODE.. [codepen](https://codepen.io/cardosource/pen/qBQJmej)
Como coloqué en el HTML fue:

primero `select` y luego las `div's`.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Answer (score 4):

La solución más práctica es guardar `this.value` en conjunto en el `sessionStorage`. Puedes hacer esto.

Como el valor que guardas es un `Array`, podemos convertirlo en un objeto para poder guardar más valores de manera indexada, difiriendo del `Array`.

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify({ items: selItems, selectionValue: this.value }));
```

De esta forma estarás guardando la elección en un apartado dentro del mismo objeto. De esta forma puedes recuperar el valor `selectionValue` en la función que ejecutas cuando se carga la página.

Puedes reemplazar estas líneas

```js
if (selItems) {
    selItems.items.forEach(obj => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
      $("#" + k).val(v)
    })
    // usar return para terminar la ejecucion
    return mostrarDiv(selItems.selectionValue);
}
```

Los cambios que hice fueron los siguientes:

1. **Terminar la ejecución del código** Usando `return`, se terminará la ejecución del código, de esta forma

```
return mostrarDiv(selItems.selectionValue);
```

En este contexto, `return` se usa para terminar la ejecución del código, ya que estamos en un contexto de "bloque". Puedes revisar el siguiente enlace: [*`return`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

2. **Iterar `selItems.items`** Como previamente guardamos los valores en el valor `items` de `selItems`, ahora podemos recuperar los datos desde `selItems.items` que contendrá los datos que guardamos anteriormente.

**Una consideración a tener en cuenta** es que **`sessionStorage` tiene un tiempo de expiración**. Por lo general, cuando cierras la página, el `sessionStorage` se reiniciará. Si quieres asegurar realmente la persistencia de los datos pase lo que pase, puedes usar `localStorage` en vez de `sessionStorage`, para hacerlo, simplemente cambia todos los `sessionStorage` por `localStorage`.

**Documentación y referencias**

- [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score -1):

Para mantener la persistencia de un div después de un REFRESH/RELOAD en una página web, puedes utilizar el almacenamiento de sesión (sessionStorage) en JavaScript.
Osea, aca te dejo un ejemplo:

```
let selItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem")) || [];

$(function () {
  if (selItems) {
    selItems.forEach(obj => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(obj)[0]
      $("#" + k).val(v)
    })
  }
  $('.term').on("change", function () {
    selItems = $('.term').map(function () {
      return {
        [this.id]: this.value
      }
    }).get();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", JSON.stringify(selItems))
    mostrarDiv(this.value)
  });
});

function mostrarDiv(target) {
  var opciones = document.getElementsByClassName('opc');
  var tagt = document.getElementById(target);
  var esVisible = tagt.style.display == 'block';

  //ocultar todo
  for (var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
    opciones[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  //toggle actual
  tagt.style.display = esVisible ? 'none' : 'block';

  return false;
}
```

Este código utiliza sessionStorage para almacenar los valores seleccionados del  en el almacenamiento de sesión del navegador. Luego, al cargar la página nuevamente, recupera estos valores del sessionStorage y los asigna a los elementos correspondientes para mantener la persistencia de la selección y mostrar el div adecuado.

Recuerda que sessionStorage se borra cuando se cierra la pestaña o el navegador, por lo que la persistencia solo se mantendrá durante la sesión actual del usuario.

Comment: pero ÉL ya estaba usando sessionStorage, esa no es la solución

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Comment: @cardosource la respuesta es generada con una IA, **obviamente** es errónea.